# Force Hover State within Media Query

Tags: html, css, hover

I am wondering what the best way to display a ":hover" on mobile media query.

For example, I have several thumbnails that have a hover state with a "More Info" button.

Since I cannot have a hover on a mobile device, what would be the best way to "lock" the hover state using the media query (so that the hover is always showing under 768px)?

Here is a Fiddle of what is currently going on:
http://jsfiddle.net/yashar/XgGFf/48/

I know this CSS is not possible, but just as an example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .figTop {
        display:hover;
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<figure class="figTop">
    <div class="ca-img">
        <img src="images/gallery/page_thumbs/ford_thumb.jpg" alt="Ford">
    </div>
    <figcaption>
        <div class="fRect">

<h5>Ford</h5>

<sub>Commercial</sub>

            <button class="btns btn-3 btn-3g" data-gallery="1">More Info</button>
        </div>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: From your description, it sounds like a simple ` display: block; ` would do exactly what you're saying.

Comment: @Renson Didn't seem to change anything. Here is a Fiddle that displays the hover state a little better: [http://jsfiddle.net/yashar/XgGFf/48/](http://jsfiddle.net/yashar/XgGFf/48/)

Comment: If all your hover state is doing is turning `opacity` to 1. Then wont simply setting your media query to do the same work?

Comment: Thanks @badAdviceGuy, that indeed was the case. All works now.